# How to remove NA value from the plot with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, na

I Have data.frame `A`(3 columns: x,value and SD)  with NA value for the same row of the three columns. 
I plot in ggplot with standard deviation (SD), the code is:

```
p <- ggplot(A,aes(x=x,y=value))
p + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=value-SD,ymax=value+SD),fill = "gray",na.rm=T)+ 
  geom_line(aes(y=value))+
  theme_bw()+ theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
                    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

the results is: 
[image]

I would not plot the NA value (in the above plot the gray square with black line), how I can do it? I need plot subset of my df `A`?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options for plotting gaps:

```
# create sample data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=runif(100),SD=0.1)
df[45:55, c("x", "y", "SD")] <- NA

# option 1: groupings
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group=cumsum(is.na(df$x)))) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=y-SD,ymax=y+SD),fill = "gray") + geom_line() 

# options 2: interpolations
ggplot(df, aes(zoo::na.approx(x), y)) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=y-SD,ymax=y+SD),fill = "gray") + geom_line()
```

Answer (score 2):

First some example data

```
A = data.frame(x = 1900:2000, value=cumsum(rnorm(101)), SD= 0.5)
A[50:60, 2:3] = NA
```

If I understand your question, you more or less had the answer. Just change `na.rm` to `FALSE`

```
p = ggplot(A,aes(x=x,y=value))
p + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=value-SD,ymax=value+SD),fill = "gray",na.rm=FALSE)+ 
  geom_line()+
  theme_bw()+ 
   theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
                    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

[image]